# SwiftUI – Displaying a variable in a view to the user

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a basic iOS device details app. Trying to print the user's iOS version in a view. I have declared a variable in the ContentView.swift file.

```
var systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
```

But, I do not know how to display this variable to the user via a view in SwiftUI.

Currently:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var selectedTab = Tab.dash

var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        
        
        NavigationView {
            VStack {

                Text("Model Name")
                
                Form {
                    
                    Section {
                    Text("iOS") //Display iOSVer around here
                    Text("Details")
                    Text("Details")
                    Text("Details")
                    Text("Details")
                    Text("Details")
                    }
                    
                    Section {
                    Text("Details")
                    Text("Details")
                    }
                    
                }
                }
            .navigationTitle("Dashboard View")
        }

        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "iphone")
            Text("Dashboard")
        .tag(Tab.dash)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
Text("iOS \(UIDevice.current.systemVersion)")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to check, can this structure be used with variables?

Text("Name \(variable)")